# single, double quotes, or tokens?

Tags: yacc

Tutorials on writing yacc code online use single quotes for semicolons, and other characters:

```
';'  '+'  '-' (etc)
```

however when using:

```
'<' or '>'
```

I got errors until I changed it to double quotes:

```
"<" or ">"
```

Similarly,

```
'>='  '=<'  '==' '!='
```

do not seem to be the same as

```
">="  "=<"  "==" "!="
```

How does yacc treat single quotes? double quotes?
And when should tokens be used instead of putting stuff in quotes?

```
ie: '!=' vs "!=" vs TOKNOTEQUALS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `'` or `"` around literals -- they're equivalent.  HOWEVER, you can in general only put a single character between the quotes and get a sensible result -- a parser that accepts that single character token.  Putting multiple characters in the quotes gives you a single token, but there's no way for your lexer to return that token, so its not useful.